# Почему код на Golang не работает?

Tags: golang

Использую VS CODE.
Вся проблема в том, что  VS Code выдаёт мне ошибку, а оф. сайт GOlang справляется. В чём проблема? Спасибо)

**Вот сам код:**

```
 package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    var age = 17
    if age < 7 {
        fmt.Println("Тебе пора в школу!")
    } else if age < 17 {
        fmt.Println("Тебе пора в институт!")
    } else if (age > 5) && (age <= 18) {
        var grade = age - 6
        fmt.Println("Пора идти в", grade, "класс")
    }
}
```

Вот ошибка, которую выдаёт консоль:

```
# _/c_/prog/GoLangExamples
.\project.go:5:6: main redeclared in this block
    previous declaration at .\golang.go:5:6
exit status 2
Process exiting with code: 1
```

Comment: У вас два файла с `main` в одной директории, вестимо.  Либо удалите или переместите, либо копайтесь в настройках *IDE.*

Comment: Спасибо, проблема пропала)

Comment: @Ainar-G как ответ оформите?

Comment: @SuvitrufsaysReinstateMonica Добавил.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как и было предположено в комментарии, проблема в том, что у вас
в директории несколько файлов с функцией `main`.  Из консоли
с этим можно работать с помощью `go run file.go`, но ваша
*IDE* такого не понимает.  Поэтому нужно либо настроить *IDE*,
либо переместить второй файл куда-то ещё.